# Form action is not using the PHP file?

Tags: php, forms, post, submit, action

I am trying to upload a file. But my form action doesn't use the code I have in "readCSV.php". Its just does nothing.

```
<p>Welkom  <b><span style='color:white;'> Admin </span></b></p>
            <p id='p1'align='left' ><b>CSV bestanden uploaden</b></p>

            <form id='csv' action=readCSV.php method=post enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type='file' name='filep'><br />
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Inladen'>
            </form>
```

What am I doing wrong? There is NO error in the readCSV.php file.

Comment: Try putting quotes around `action=readCSV.php method=post` as in `action="readCSV.php" method="post"` that usually is something that will break your code. You should also post your PHP. Plus, on some systems, `readCSV.php` and `readcsv.php` is case-senstive, however this would have shown you a 404, but let's not leave it out of the equation ;-)

Comment: `But my form action doesn't use the code I have in "readCSV.php".` How do you know this? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

All attributes in HTML need quotes around them. Technically, you can use single quotes or double quotes, but they need something to mark them off as attributes. This is missing several quotes:

```
<form id='csv' action=readCSV.php method=post enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

And should be this:

```
<form id="csv" action="readCSV.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes in HTML tag.